# Adding Wordpress Blog to Existing Website: Is Database Required

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system

I have been asked to add a Wordpress blog to an existing website and wanted to ask the group a few tech questions.

The website is static, does not run with a database in the background, was created with plain html/css and is hosted on a generic server.

If I were to add a blog to this site, would I need to set up a database to hold the content?

If no database is needed, could content be uploaded/removed using ftp software one would normally use to manage a website like this?

Could the original Wordpress navigation and css be replaced with the css and navigation for the website?

Could the blog support widgets like as 'like' or 'add this' without the use of a database?

If anyone has insights they can share I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install WordPress, you will need a database. Check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Things_to_Know_Before_Installing_WordPress) for the full list of requirements for installing WP.

Other than this, yes, you can mimic the navigation and design of the main website by creating a [custom theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).